# DateTimeFormatter for Date to String throwing Exception

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an array of `String` representation of Dates using streams and `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
public static String[] sortDatesAsString(DateTimeFormatter formatter, String[] dates) {
    return Arrays.stream(dates)
            .map(date -> LocalDate.parse(date, formatter))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream().sorted()
            .map((d) -> d.format(formatter))
            .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arr[] = new String[]{"02/02/2010", "3/11/2011", "11/3/2011", "4/4/2011"};
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm/dd/yyyy");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortDatesAsString(formatter, arr)));
}
```

I am getting the following exception while trying to format the sorted dates back to `String`to return.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02/02/2010' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=2, MinuteOfHour=2, Year=2010},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
```

I am having trouble understanding the Exception.

Comment: There's an error in your pattern. `mm` is minutes. Use `MM` for months: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: mm/dd/yyyy should be MM/dd/yyyy because mm is for minutes and MM for month.

Comment: Read the message error  `DayOfMonth=2, MinuteOfHour=2, Year=2010` You have a wrong pattern sine you have `MinuteOfHour` with `mm` ... that can't fit in a `LocalDate`. You want `MM` for month. See the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) documentation for the full explanation

Comment: @Jesper Thanks a ton! It's silly of me to not notice. However, this format only parses `02/02/2010` and not `2/2/2010`. Is there something that can be done regarding this?

Comment: Got it! The required format is M/d/yyyy. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the exception message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02/02/2010' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=2, MinuteOfHour=2, Year=2010},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
```

You can see that it parsed your date like

```
TemporalAccessor: {
    DayOfMonth=2, 
    MinuteOfHour=2, 
    Year=2010
}
```

This is not what you want. A `MinuteOfHour` (m) doesn't fit in a `LocalDate`.

If you check [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) documentation you will see that `Month` is

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J
```

not

```
m       minute-of-hour              number            30
```

**Please, read the exception fully, 90% of the time, the answer is in it...**